# css & js not working in rails production mode

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i do

```
thin start --ssl -p 4000 -e production
```

It starts my server all content is visible but without any css & js not working,
I check many documents & following things can do , but nothing happend

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true  
 config.assets.compile = true

 config.assets.precompile += %w(
shopqi_application.js shopqi_wiki_application.js admin_application.js checkout_application.js active_admin.js
layout_application.css layout_admin.css layout_admin_print.css layout_shopqi.css
shopqi_ie-signup.css layout_shopqi_theme.css active_admin.css layout_shopqi_wiki.css
layout_checkout.css admin/layout_doorkeeper_authorization.css
ie6.css ie-admin.css ie7.css ie-checkout.css ie.css ie-themes.css ie7-themes.css DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js)
```

I also do

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

manually clean the public/assets , but nothing happend.

Comment: Does it work without your SSL option when starting the server?

Comment: i forcefully start my server on https.

Comment: Yes I know - but if you start in `http`, does the problem persist? If so, it means the issue is with `SSL`, if not, it's likely a rails issue

Comment: No i configured it, like ,site is only starts in https

Comment: Okay well I'm afraid you're going to have this problem for a long time then. Software development is as much about testing as it is writing code - if you're not willing to test for us, we can't really help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details about [assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html).

In `production.rb`:-

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
#config.assets.precompile += %w(shopqi_application.js shopqi_wiki_application.js admin_application.js checkout_application.js active_admin.js layout_application.css layout_admin.css layout_admin_print.css layout_shopqi.css shopqi_ie-signup.css layout_shopqi_theme.css active_admin.css layout_shopqi_wiki.css layout_checkout.css admin/layout_doorkeeper_authorization.css ie6.css ie-admin.css ie7.css ie-checkout.css ie.css ie-themes.css ie7-themes.css DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js)
```

Add this in `application.rb` in `config/`:-

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false
```

Add these lines in `application.js`:-

```
//= require shopqi_application
//= require shopqi_wiki_application
//= require admin_application
//= require checkout_application
//= require active_admin
//= require DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min
```

Add these lines in `application.css`:-

```
*= require layout_application
*= require layout_admin
*= require layout_admin_print
*= require layout_shopqi
*= require shopqi_ie-signup
*= require layout_shopqi_theme
*= require active_admin
*= require layout_shopqi_wiki
*= require layout_checkout
*= require admin/layout_doorkeeper_authorization
*= require ie6
*= require ie-admin
*= require ie7
*= require ie-checkout
*= require ie
*= require ie-themes
*= ie7-themes
```

Then :-

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Start the server as:-

```
thin start -p 4000 -e production
```

To start the server so that it always running after closing the terminal:-

```
thin start -p 4000 -d -e production
```

Comment: Thanks for reply again , but this one also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try->

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```